# osrm's response order after consecutive requests in a short time

Tags: qt, real-time, osrm, map-matching

I'm using QT to make requests to OSRM (Match service) with a frequency of 16ms/request. I'm wondering how to know which response corresponds to which request. Does it return sequentially in FIFO order? Because the document does not mention this issue (https://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.24.0/api/#match-service)

Example:

- Request: req1, req2, req3,...
- Respone: res1, res2, res3,...

PC:
CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400

RAM 16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)